# Implementation recommendations (tutorial) for implementing a linq interface

Tags: .net, linq, api, linq-to-entities, standards

Developing a .net library based on an industry standard. The standard includes data structures and an api for interacting with a server.

I am considering adding a Linq friendly implementation, and to try to either implment or emulate Linq to Entities. The obvious difference is the API is used for CRUD operations, instead of a database server.

I have seen a lot of various articles and tutorials on how to implement parts of this, but was curious if someone can recommend a more comprehensive, start-to-finish guide for this sort of undertaking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out:

- Matt Warren's comprehensive blog posts: [LINQ: Building an IQueryable provider series](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2008/11/18/linq-links.aspx)
- MSDN article: [Walkthrough: Creating an IQueryable LINQ Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546158.aspx)